# Redirecting the url entered with htaccess to a different location in the same way

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, forwarding

When I enter my `example.com` url I want to redirect to `example.com/en/` but when I enter `example.com/demo` I want to redirect to `example.com/us/demo`. The word demo here is just variable. how can I do that ?

My .htaccess code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /tr/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /tr/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following before your existing directives (ie. *before* the `<IfModule>` section):

```
# Redirect "/" to "/en/"
RewriteRule ^$ /en/ [R,L]

# Redirect "/demo" to "/us/demo"
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(en|us)/
RewriteRule (.*) /us/$1 [R,L]
```

The first rule redirects `example.com/` to `example.comn/en/`. The second rule redirects everything else to `/us/<url>`, providing the URL-path does not already start `/en/` or `/us/`.

If you also need to make an exception for your static assets... eg. Should a request for `/assets/images/img.png` also be redirected? Then include an additional condition (as the 2nd condition) on the second rule:

```
# Redirect "/demo" to "/us/demo" (and exclude static assets)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(en|us)/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.*) /us/$1 [R,L]
```

Note that these are 302 (temporary) redirects.